# How would I go about implementing an HTTP proxy with WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, http, proxy

For my application, I need to implement an HTTP/S Proxy server in C#.

Some answers on this site suggest to use the `TcpClient` and `TcpListener` classes for maximum flexibility. I have, in the past, taken this route and I know it can work quite well, however, I would not like to be overwhelmed with the task of re-implementing the finicky details of *pipelining*, connection management, encodings, etc.

Another solution is to take advantage of existing proxies, such as [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore), or [Mentalis](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/), suggested in several answers here on StackOverflow.

The reason I'm specifically asking about WCF is that I would like to take advantage of its flexibility. Especially, I would like to eventually expose the proxy as a [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/) [Service Bus Relay](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-relay/) Service. I have perused the [various extensibility points offered by WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx) but I'm lost as to which one will help in my case.

**Update**

To clarify, this is *almost* what I need:
http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.fr/2008/11/writing-simple-http-proxy-using-wcf.html

However, this is not a strict HTTP proxy since it has a service contract. I really need to be able to browse, say, the Stack Overflow web site, by typing the url of the proxy in my browser's address bar. All traffic should be intercepted by the HTTP proxy and redirected as appropriate to Stack Overflow, for instance.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508619/wcf-data-service-proxy-mid-tier-service

Comment: Why dont you use Service Bus Relay Service right away? Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx ? But perhaps it's not related al all since I don't know how the Service Bus Relay works!

Comment: @Paul, thanks for the feedback. I fail to see how it can be of some help, though. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Jocke, I need more than *Routing*. In fact, ideally, I would like to be able to browse to any web site by pointing a browser to the proxy.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93301/Implementing-a-Multithreaded-HTTP-HTTPS-Debugging

Comment: @Paul, that covers my first paragraph, where I explicitely suggest I would rather not follow this route.

Comment: WCF routing would appear to be what you need

Comment: @hugh, thanks for that. That looks promising. I managed to make it working by routing a simple service to another one. But I cannot succeed in making an Internet Browser talk to my routing service. I really need an HTTP proxy, in order to be able to browse, say, the Google web site from my proxy. Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: _"For my application, I need to implement an HTTP/S Proxy server in C#."_ - you probably don't. Care to elaborate on why you think you need to implement an HTTP proxy, what existing solutions can't offer, and what advantages WCF offers over a socket (or really, any existing) implementation? Anyway, if you want to be able to use your WCF HTTP Proxy as system proxy, you'll need a custom binding that can convert any HTTP request into a message for your WCF service. An HTTP request from a browser is not a SOAP request. You're not there with just the URL, what about headers and cookies and so on?

Comment: My scenario does not make sense at a technical level, but for business reasons. We are already able to access on-premise LOB applications with zero impact on the firewall from our cloud-based application. Now, we would like to be able to expose an on-premise intranet web app on the cloud through our solution. It happens that requesting the company to install a reverse-proxy and open some firewall ports takes months. With an HTTP proxy, we could be up in weeks instead. I know, I know... don't get me started... :-)